# How to get Size of a file in Asp

Tags: asp.net, size, filesize

> hi,
>
> i am able to get all files in a directory with their path and their files with this code.

```
    List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                   
    string Myfile = "";
               
    foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    {
    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
    }
```

> But i cant get sizes of these files. How can i do that. i cant use size property like,

```
     files[0].size;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) instance and then ask for the size using the [`Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
    long fileSizeInBytes = fi.Length;
    files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
}
```

The Length property will give you the file size in bytes that you could use.